# Help with a property of a convex function

Tags: calculus, linear-programming, convex-optimization

I'm studying linear and nonlinear programming and on my book I bumped into the following statement:

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \displaystyle \frac{f(\textbf{x}+\alpha (\textbf{y}-\textbf{x}))-f(\textbf{x})}{\alpha} = \nabla f(\textbf{x})(\textbf{y}-\textbf{x})$$

Could someone show me, why is the statement above true?...I get confused again with this for some reason :-)

Thank you for any help :-)

Comment: Wups, i have a mistake in my latex, sorry about that...i will try to find the mistake ASAP

Comment: Found it :-) and corrected :-)

Comment: This is true for any function $f$ that is differentiable at $x$.  We don't need any convexity assumptions.  You can prove it using the multivariable chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the equation is saying nothing more that the directional derivative of a differentiable function is equal to the inner product of the direction and the gradient of that function:
Your left hand side is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $(y-x)$ and your right hand side is the inner product of the gradient of $f$ at $x$ with the direction $(y-x)$.